# Восстановление последовательности событий по условию

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Есть таблица следующего вида:

| user_id | source | visit_time | transact | transact_Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2122547835443026286 | google_cpc | 2017-07-12 22:36:07 UTC | 0 | Null |
| 2122547835443026286 | google_cpc | 2017-07-12 22:36:07 UTC | 0 | Null |
| 2122547835443026286 | google_cpc | 2017-07-12 22:36:07 UTC | 0 | Null |
| 2122547835443026286 | google_organic | 2017-07-12 23:20:17 UTC | 1 | 21423421 |
| 2122547835443026286 | google_organic | 2017-07-12 23:20:17 UTC | 1 | 21423421 |
| 2122547835443026286 | google_organic | 2017-07-12 23:20:17 UTC | 1 | 21423421 |

user_id - идентификатор пользователя
source - канал привлечения
visit_time - время посещения страницы
transact - была или не была осуществлена транзакция (покупка)

Если пользователь совершает покупку, то у него transact становится = 1, это означает, что для этой строки нужно найти все предыдущие переходы до момента транзакции.

Если пользователь так и не совершил транзакцию, то у него в Touchpoint должно быть None.

Результат:

| transact_Id | Touchpoint |
| --- | --- |
| Null | NaN |
| 21423421 | google_cpc > google_organic |

Comment: Нет, так не пойдёт. Распишите по шагам. Вот есть такие-то данные. Куда нужно смотреть и что делать, если допустим человек смотрит на эти данные. Как он должен получить результат который ниже, исполнив какие шаги? Вот когда это распишете - тогда можно думать, как это алгоритмизировать. А заниматься за вас аналитикой - это отдельная работа. Во многих задачах программирование это 10% работы, а аналитика - 90%. А бывает, что и 99%. В настоящий момент непонятно, что вы хотите и как получить искомый результат. И лучше привести несколько пользователей с разными вариантами результатов.

Comment: @CrazyElf
 Есть первая таблица, в которой отображаются сеансы посещения пользователем сайта.  В source указывается откуда он перешел на сайт. Например, если source = google, значит с сайта гугла. Пользователь зачастую не с первого перехода осуществляет какую-то покупку. Если он что-то покупает на сайте, то это регистрируется событием transact=1. Если пользователь что-то купил, то нужно понимать с каких каналов он переходил до момента покупки. Исходя из выше указанной таблицы есть 1 пользователь 2122547835443026286, у него было 2 сессий захода на сайт (время visit_time разное).

Comment: @CrazyElf Таким образом для transact_Id = 21423421 и user_id= 2122547835443026286 собираем все его каналы захода, а было их 2 google_cpc и google_organic. Т.е в новой таблице по  transact_Id = 21423421 должна быть новая колонка в которой будет заполнено google_cpc --> google_organic. Если бы у пользователя был еще один заход, скажем с канала yandex, то новая колонка содержала бы значения google_cpc --> google_organic --> yandex. Если у пользователя не было транзакции, значит и цепочки каналов не должно быть.

Comment: Так вроде понятнее, хорошо. Потом подумаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Много непонятного в деталях. Для начала можно сделать так:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': [2122547835443026286] * 6 + [2122547835443026300] * 6,
                   'source': ['google_cpc', 'google_cpc', 'yandex', 'google_organic', 'google_organic',
                              'google_organic'] + ['google_cpc', 'google_cpc', 'google_cpc', 'google_organic',
                                                   'google_organic',
                                                   'google_organic'],
                   'visit_time': ['2017-07-12 22:36:07 UTC', '2017-07-12 22:36:07 UTC',
                                  '2017-07-12 22:36:07 UTC', '2017-07-12 23:20:17 UTC',
                                  '2017-07-12 23:20:17 UTC', '2017-07-12 23:20:17 UTC'] * 2,
                   'transact': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1] + [0] * 6,
                   'transact_Id': ['Null', 'Null', 'Null', '21423421', '21423421', '21423421'] + ['123456'] * 6})
df.visit_time = pd.to_datetime(df.visit_time)


def fun(x):
    if x.transact.any():
        return pd.Series([x.loc[x.transact.eq(1), 'transact_Id'].max(),
                          ' > '.join(dict.fromkeys(x.sort_values(['transact', 'visit_time']).source).keys())],
                         index=['transact_Id', 'Touchpoint'])
    return pd.Series([x.transact_Id.max(), None], index=['transact_Id', 'Touchpoint'])


df1 = df.groupby('user_id').apply(fun)
print(df1)
```

```
                    transact_Id                            Touchpoint
user_id                                                              
2122547835443026286    21423421  google_cpc > yandex > google_organic
2122547835443026300      123456                                  None
```